# assign unique list number to group of data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am using oracle database 10g.

I am stuck in one logic implementation of client requirement.

We have following data in table ::

```
id  cust_nbr item_id    
---------------------
1       A       10 
2       A       11 
3       A       12 
4       B       10 
5       B       11 
6       B       12 
7       C       11 
8       C       12 
9       C       13 
10      C       14
```

Expected out put ::

```
id  cust_nbr item_id    list_nbr
---------------------------------------
1       A       10      1
2       A       11      1
3       A       12      1
4       B       10      1
5       B       11      1
6       B       12      1
7       C       11      2
8       C       12      2
9       C       13      2
10      C       14      2
```

We want to assign unique list number to all same item which are having different customer.

As you can see here item_id 10,11,12 is assigned  to 2 customer(A,B) so for that list_nbr 1 is assigned to this 2 customer.
item_id 11,12,13,14 is assigned to 1 customer(C) only so list_nbr 2 is assigned to this customer.

I am not able to find any way to implement this change using sql.

This data is just an example. There will be thousands of record in this table.

Could you please help me to figure out this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:  I'm leaving this answer but it applies to Oracle 11g, not 10g.  You can try to replace `listagg()` with `wm_concat()`, but the `order by` within the groups is important for this solution.

One method is to use `listagg()` to bring the values together and then assign a value.  So, by customer, this would be:

```
select cust_nbr, listagg(item_id, ',') within group (order by item_id) as items
from t
group by cust_nbr;
```

You can assign a unique value using `dense_rank()`:

```
select cust_nbr,
       listagg(item_id, ',') within group (order by item_id) as items,
       dense_rank() over (order by listagg(item_id, ',') within group (order by item_id)) as list_nbr
from t
group by cust_nbr;
```

You can then join this back to your data:

```
with l as (
      select cust_nbr,
             listagg(item_id, ',') within group (order by item_id) as items,
             dense_rank() over (order by listagg(item_id, ',') within group (order by item_id)) as list_nbr
      from t
      group by cust_nbr
     )
select t.*, l.list_nbr
from t join
     l
     on t.cust_nbr = l.cust_nbr;
```

Comment: LISTAGG() was introduced in 11g. The OP says they are using 10g

Comment: @APC . . . I added the tag to the question.